# Css3 card flip animation, why is it rotating to one side? Trying to make it rotate around the center of the card

Tags: css, 3d, transform, flip

I'm trying to use this example: http://desandro.github.com/3dtransforms/examples/card-01.html

But when I copied the css, to make a demo of it to play with on jsfiddle, it rotates kind of around one side, it almost swings when it flips.

I'm trying to make it act like the example, but I don't know what's wrong. How do I make it flip like the demo does?

my jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/nicktheandroid/RrtVy/

Comment: Did yours work in IE? I found the card flip effect doesn't work in IE 11?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's inheriting a declaration from styles.css which is not in the inlined code. Just add

```
#card figure {
  ...
  margin: 0;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/yuYyW/

Comment: I don't understand why I need to add `margin: 0` when there's no margin set in the css code. How could it be inheriting margin when there's no margin set? Is it the browsers default margin for the `figure` element?

Comment: If you use the Web Inspector your will see the user agent adds 1em of margin before and after the figure (similar to tables). Since the font is so large, that 1em amounts to a pretty large margin.

Comment: Is there a way to have it correctly rotate(twist) around it's center like it should do from the example on the website I listed, but WITH padding and/or margin? So in the example below, I put 5px of padding onto `#card div`, and that's causing it to rotate just a little bit off it's center, is there a way to keep the padding and make it rotate around it's center? new jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/nicktheandroid/RrtVy/2/

Comment: You are stating the width and height of #card, so when you add padding/margin to #card div it still rotates around the center of #card, not #card div. The solution is to not state the width and height of #card, http://jsfiddle.net/hnknC/

Comment: I found that this card flip doesn't work in the latest version of IE. Do you know what I can do to get around it?